# saving a dash layout to html file

Tags: python, html, plotly

I plotted a bunch of things in a dash layout. I want to save them to an html file so I can look at them later. when I reopen the saved html file, I first see everything correctly. However, within <2s, the page goes blank and I get an error: “Error loading layout”.

How can this be fixed?

Thanks!